# How to force join order in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

When we join `t1` to `t2` to `t3` to `t4` we can go:

```
t3->t4->t2->t1
t1->t2->t3->t4
t4->t3->t2->t1
.....
```

Is there any way that we force optimizer in SQL Server to start from specific table in the join chain? Something like leading in Oracle

I am looking for a solution like leading  (in Oracle) in SQL Server.

Comment: start with dependent PK table which you are using as a join

Comment: @tinka, does that really matter?

Comment: @jarlh yes it would be great if we filter the page based on Primary key (PK) which should be first

Comment: @tinka Does PK stand for Primary key?

Answer (score 7):

If, in addition to the order of the joins, you know what types of joins, then you can be explicit:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 HASH JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID;
```

This enforces the ordering as well the type (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx)).

If you want to specify the use of a particular type of join without forcing the order, then use `option` instead.  And, use `force order` if you want the ordering but not the type.  However, the SQL Server optimizer is usually pretty good, so `force order` is rarely needed.

Comment: Generally you are awesome Sir.

Answer (score 3):

There is FORCE ORDER hint:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution except FORCE ORDER

Comment: You mean you want to force only subset of tables but not all?

Comment: I would like to strat from t2 for example

Comment: Then I guess the only option is to provide your own execution plan.